# Java Servlet mapping

Tags: java, servlets

### **Servlet Mapping**

I am new to java ee 6.I am trying to get a servlet request.Every other mapping works fine except /category mapping. Here is my ControllerServlet class.I have used @webServlet annotion for mapping.I have tried to do the mapping in web.xml but no luck.Using netbeans IDE 7.2,Server Glassfish opensource.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    @WebServlet(name = "ControllerServlet",
    loadOnStartup = 1,
    urlPatterns = {
    "/addToCart",
    "/viewCart",
    "/updateCart",
    "/checkout",
    "/purchase",
    "/chooseLanguage",
    "/category"})

    public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {


/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userPath = request.getServletPath();



    // if cart page is requested
    if (userPath.equals("/viewCart")) {
        userPath = "/cart";
    }

    //if category page is requested
    else if (userPath.equals("/category")) { 
    } 

    // if ckeckout page is requested
    else if (userPath.equals("/checkout")){
      //  System.out.println("check");

    }

    // if user switches language
    else if (userPath.equals("/chooseLanguage")){


    }

    // use RequestDispatcher to forward request internally

    String url = "/WEB-INF/View" + userPath + ".jsp";
    System.out.print(url);

    try{
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}



/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userPath = request.getServletPath();

    // if addToCart action is called
    if (userPath.equals("/addToCart")) {
        // TODO: Implement add product to cart action

    // if updateCart action is called
    } else if (userPath.equals("/updateCart")) {
        // TODO: Implement update cart action

    // if purchase action is called
    } else if (userPath.equals("/purchase")) {
        // TODO: Implement purchase action

        userPath = "/confirmation";
    }

    // use RequestDispatcher to forward request internally
    String url = "/WEB-INF/view" + userPath + ".jsp";

    try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

[Link to image of web-inf directory](http://www.flickr.com/photos/50915041@N04/)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can simplify your code a lot by just having a separate servlet for each action.

Comment: Why the heck has this question with a poor title, a terrible piece of code and a seemingly obvious typo-mistake 4 upvotes? How exactly is this question useful and well researched?

Answer (score 0):

`/categories` is not mapped in your servlet. `/category` *is* mapped however.

Comment: I saw the same but PLEASE...don´t let that be the solution. That should be the stupiedst typo for months.